# kubernetes persistent volume showing pending

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Hi All I use GKE and created a cluster in Google cloud.
Here is my Persistent volume

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mongo-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 256Mi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: /tmp/db
```

Here is the command that created persistent volume

```
kubectl create -f mongo-pv.yaml
```

persistentvolumeclaim

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mongo-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  volumeName: mongo-pv
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 256Mi
```

applied using

```
kubectl create -f mongo-pvc.yaml
```

however the command to get pvc always shows pending. It should be showing up. Not sure what is wrong in the yaml files

```
kubectl get pvc
NAME        STATUS    VOLUME     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
mongo-pvc   Pending   mongo-pv   0                         standard-rwo
```

**Update**

```
 kubectl describe pvc mongo-pvc
Name:          mongo-pvc
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:  standard-rwo
Status:        Pending
Volume:        mongo-pv
Labels:        <none>
Annotations:   <none>
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      0
Access Modes:  
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Used By:       <none>
Events:
  Type     Reason          Age                  From                         Message
  ----     ------          ----                 ----                         -------
  Warning  VolumeMismatch  23s (x262 over 65m)  persistentvolume-controller  Cannot bind to requested volume "mongo-pv": storageClassName does not match
```

Comment: can you attach the output of `kubectl describe pvc mongo-pvc` ?

Comment: @faizan I just updated.

Answer (score 1):

Your PV's storage class name is empty but your PVC's storage class name is filled automatically as `standard-rwo` because of the DefaultStorageClass admission plugin.

These paragraphs are from [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#class-1):

> A claim can request a particular class by specifying the name of a StorageClass using the attribute storageClassName. Only PVs of the requested class, ones with the same storageClassName as the PVC, can be bound to the PVC.

> PVCs don't necessarily have to request a class. A PVC with its storageClassName set equal to "" is always interpreted to be requesting a PV with no class, so it can only be bound to PVs with no class (no annotation or one set equal to ""). A PVC with no storageClassName is not quite the same and is treated differently by the cluster, depending on whether the DefaultStorageClass admission plugin is turned on.

I guess you should either **turn off DefaultStorageClass admission plugin and apply your manifests again** or **give your PV the same storage class name** like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mongo-pv
spec:
  storageClassName: standard-rwo
  capacity:
    storage: 256Mi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: /tmp/db
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error indicates, it's not pointing to the correct `storageClass`. Check if the storageClass `standard-rwo` exists already with with `kubectl get sc` (create one if there's none) and add the `storageClassName` while claiming the volume. You don't need to create a PV explicitly, when you create a PVC using `storageClass`,it will automatically provision a PV object for you.